# How to give Floating version in nuget package to get latest dependency

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I refered Dependency resolution in NuGet 3.x at below url https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution#dependency-resolution-in-nuget-3x

There are 4 rules 
1) Lowest applicable version 
2) Floating versions 
3) Nearest wins 
4) Cousin dependencies

1st, 3d and 4th we can define in package while 2nd we can set in package.json

How can i set floating version on nuget package?

I have total 3 project say ProjectA, ProjectB, ProjectC

ProjectB referes ProjectA, Project.json is like

```
"dependencies": {"ProjectA": "1.0.0."}
```

ProjectC referes ProjectB, Project.json is like

```
"dependencies": {"ProjectB": "1.0.0."}
```

Available packages on nuget feed

```
ProjectA.1.0.0.1 
ProjectA.1.0.0.2 
ProjectB.1.0.0.1 
ProjectB.1.0.0.2
```

---

**Now if i compile ProjectB**

it will take latest ProjectA in bin folder. i.e. **ProjectA.1.0.0.2 [Floating Versions Rule]**

it creates nuget package of ProjectB with dependency ProjectA >= 1.0.0

**My requirement is to create package like ProjectA = 1.0.0.* to take latest available dependency.**

---

**Now if i compile ProjectC**

it will take latest ProjectB in bin folder. i.e. **ProjectB.1.0.0.2 [Floating Versions Rule]**

it will take lowest ProjectA in bin folder. i.e. **ProjectA.1.0.0.1 [Lowest applicable version]**

it creates nuget package of ProjectC with dependency ProjectB >= 1.0.0

I tried with below option and it also didn't worked for me

```
"dependencies": {"ProjectA": "[,2.0)"} 
"dependencies": {"ProjectA": "(,2.0]"} 
"dependencies": {"ProjectA": "(,2.0)"}
```

To solve this issue manually i need to specify all dependency in project.json with floating version like nuget 2x.

```
"dependencies": {"ProjectB": "1.0.0.", "ProjectA": "1.0.0." and so on.... }
```

Comment: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4937 currently there is no other solution then to manually specifying all the dependencies in project.json like you did. But we have this workitem in our backlog to work upon and we'll soon be working on it.